# Extract data from nested array for multiple columns

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2016 and want to extract data from array.

But I got stuck.

```sql
DECLARE @idvalue NVARCHAR(MAX)='[{"testId":"b29b2327-527c-456d-8346-6bd22d198f21","testValue":"FAILURE","test":"b29b2327-527c-456d-8346-6bd22d198f21:FAILURE","testStartTimestamp":"2020-06-25T09:22:17.299Z"}
,{"testId":"4674bc9c-9551-496b-b488-8e138a4dc459","testValue":"FAILURE","test":"4674bc9c-9551-496b-b488-8e138a4dc459:FAILURE","testStartTimestamp":"2020-06-25T09:22:17.299Z"},{"testId":"38c20ac5-dbb7-43ad-b139-f8fde13d0ea5","testValue":"FAILURE","test":"38c20ac5-dbb7-43ad-b139-f8fde13d0ea5:FAILURE","testStartTimestamp":"2020-06-25T09:22:17.3Z"},{"testId":"4a3b3102-d3fa-4c2c-b3cf-46e6822fae5c","testValue":"FAILURE","test":"4a3b3102-d3fa-4c2c-b3cf-46e6822fae5c:FAILURE","testStartTimestamp":"2020-06-25T09:22:17.3Z"},{"testId":"f80bec6d-ab5c-4f63-8aea-cd2f5179195e","testValue":"FAILURE","test":"f80bec6d-ab5c-4f63-8aea-cd2f5179195e:FAILURE","testStartTimestamp":"2020-06-25T09:22:17.3Z"},{"testId":"e75896d2-f314-4423-87be-ea70b2ba5adb","testValue":"FAILURE","test":"e75896d2-f314-4423-87be-ea70b2ba5adb:FAILURE","testStartTimestamp":"2020-06-25T09:22:17.301Z"}]';

select P_conversations_conversationId,
       P_conversations_participants_sessions_flow_outcomes,
       JSON_VALUE(REPLACE(P_conversations_participants_sessions_flow_outcomes,'[',''),'$.testId') as testId,
       JSON_VALUE(REPLACE(REPLACE(P_conversations_participants_sessions_flow_outcomes,'[',''),']',''),'$.testEndTimestamp') as testEndTimestamp,
       JSON_VALUE(REPLACE(@idvalue,'[',''),'$.testValue') AS [testValue],
       JSON_VALUE(REPLACE(@idvalue,'[',''),'$.testStartTimestamp') as testStartTimestamp,
       JSON_VALUE(REPLACE(@idvalue,'[',''),'$.test') as test 
FROM Dashboardtable;
```

In the `declare` statement I have given sample data.

Comment: So what's wrong with your SQL? Where did you get stuck? We can't run the above, as we don't have access to your instance, and you haven't given us DDL and DML for your table `dbo.Dashboardtable`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Msg 13609, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
JSON text is not properly formatted. Unexpected character ',' is found at position 201.

Comment: This is what I have encountered when I am trying to execute the sql.

Comment: An approach, based on `OPENJSON` and explicit schema, is probbaly your first option.

Comment: I have tried with OPENJSON. I am getting NULL values for the datetime columns

Comment: For dates I do like so: (1) get date as string `OPENJSON(@value) WITH ( dateValue varchar(40))` and then (2) convert it to date `TRY_CONVERT(datetime, dateValue, 127)` (127 is a style "ISO8601 with time zone Z", and You can choose what suits You best) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#date-and-time-styles)

Answer (score 1):

Yoy may try to parse the input JSON with `OPENJSON()` and explicit schema:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM OPENJSON(@idvalue) WITH (
    testId varchar(36) '$.testId',
    testValue varchar(100) '$.testValue',
    test varchar(100) '$.test',
    testStartTimestamp datetime2(3) '$.testStartTimestamp'
 )
```

Result:

```
testId                                  testValue   test                                             testStartTimestamp
b29b2327-527c-456d-8346-6bd22d198f21    FAILURE     b29b2327-527c-456d-8346-6bd22d198f21:FAILURE    2020-06-25 09:22:17.299
4674bc9c-9551-496b-b488-8e138a4dc459    FAILURE     4674bc9c-9551-496b-b488-8e138a4dc459:FAILURE    2020-06-25 09:22:17.299
38c20ac5-dbb7-43ad-b139-f8fde13d0ea5    FAILURE     38c20ac5-dbb7-43ad-b139-f8fde13d0ea5:FAILURE    2020-06-25 09:22:17.300
4a3b3102-d3fa-4c2c-b3cf-46e6822fae5c    FAILURE     4a3b3102-d3fa-4c2c-b3cf-46e6822fae5c:FAILURE    2020-06-25 09:22:17.300
f80bec6d-ab5c-4f63-8aea-cd2f5179195e    FAILURE     f80bec6d-ab5c-4f63-8aea-cd2f5179195e:FAILURE    2020-06-25 09:22:17.300
e75896d2-f314-4423-87be-ea70b2ba5adb    FAILURE     e75896d2-f314-4423-87be-ea70b2ba5adb:FAILURE    2020-06-25 09:22:17.301
```

If the JSON content is stored in a table, you need an additional `APPLY` operator:

```
SELECT j.*
-- FROM Dashboardtable d
FROM (VALUES (@idvalue)) d (P_conversations_participants_sessions_flow_outcomes)
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON(d.P_conversations_participants_sessions_flow_outcomes) WITH (
   testId varchar(36) '$.testId',
   testValue varchar(100) '$.testValue',
   test varchar(100) '$.test',
   testStartTimestamp datetime2(3) '$.testStartTimestamp'
) j
```

As an additional option, if you want to extract scalar values from JSON array, you need to use an index in the `path` definition:

```
SELECT
   JSON_VALUE(@idvalue, '$[0].testValue') AS testValue,
   JSON_VALUE(@idvalue, '$[0].testStartTimestamp') AS testStartTimestamp,
   JSON_VALUE(@idvalue, '$[0].test') AS test
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. index path will not be static. It can be changed dynamically based on data. It can be 1, 2 and may be more also.

Comment: @kathija OK. In this case usisng `OPENJSON` to parse all JSON items should be your first option.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming* you just want the data out of the variable, then you can use `OPENJSON`. If not, then you need to tell us what you're actually after.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@idvalue)
     WITH(testId uniqueidentifier,
          testValue varchar(10),
          test uniqueidentifier,
          testStartTimestamp datetimeoffset(1));
```

Comment: Sorry for posting wrong data.It has been updated. There we have enddatetime also and hat is coming as NULL. I tried with the above query as well. Still this also giving NULL for enddatetime column

Comment: There *is* not `endatetime` (or I assume you mean `testEndTimestamp`) node in your data, @kathija , so of course it'll return `NULL`.